# The correct way to search for a substring in a string

Tags: c++, substring, sse, sse4

the most part of my question is: how to deal with the cases when a string loaded into `__m128i` contains only part of a substring?

the requirement: to search escaped sequences or the '"' (double quoting, not escaped) at the same time.

examples: (there is no double-quoting at start)

1. `some string ending with"`
2. `some string \"with nested\" string"`
3. `some string with\\n escaped new line"`
4. `some string with\\uDABF hex"`

the simple case: `\\n`, `\\r`. in that case I'm just looking for `\\` char using [_mm_cmpestri()](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_cmpestri), and, if the result is pointing to the last char - to r-shift it by one char using [_mm_bsrli_si128()](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_bsrli_si128) and insert one char at last position using [_mm_insert_epi8()](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm_insert_epi8) to check it for validity.

but there is a more complicated case when it is necessary to validate a `\\uDABF`-like sequences.

unlike `strchr()/strstr()` the `_mm_cmpestri()` with `_SIDD_CMP_EQUAL_ANY` allows to search for `{'\\', '"'}` at once call because the `'\\'` has a higher priority than `\"`.

at the moment it seems to me that I'm using a completely illogical approach to solving this problem using SIMD...

perhaps there are some common practices for solving such problems using SIMD?

Comment: Why even use intrinsics? Do you have proven performance problems? You might want to try std::algorithms with par_unseq and let the compiler do all the code generation for you.  In practice its very hard to outperform modern compilers : [What has my compiler done for me lately - Mat Godbolt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: Have you looked at existing standard library `strstr` implementations, like glibc's (LGPL licensed), or FreeBSD's?  Glibc's SSE2 version is https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr-sse2-unaligned.S.html using just `pcmpeqb`.  I'd guess that if you find a candidate start point, you might just do a scalar unaligned compare from that point.  Loads of data you've already loaded recently are fast (L1d hit), and often more efficient than shuffling.  In case of a cache-line split, still not a disaster.

Comment: You do need to take care of going off the end of a page, though, e.g. a `'\'` 1 byte before the end of a page could be followed by a `0` terminator, with the next page unmapped, so it wouldn't be safe to do a 4-byte load from that address to check for `'\\uD'`

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you your reply! I just explained the topic for `_mm_cmpestri()` reasons.

Comment: For large files, the [simdjson paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08318) describes SIMD tokenizing fairly well.